# React-Native Android ReactContext returning null

Tags: android, react-native

As the React-Native `AppState` API is iOS only I'm writing an appState event emitter for the Android side of my app. In the app's `MainActivity` on the Java side, I want to emit from the `onResume` and `onPause` functions to tell the JS side over the bridge that my app is either in the **foreground** or **background**

At the moment, I can minimise my app (and go back to the home-screen on my device) and the **background** event is emitted correctly. However, when I resume my app nothing is fired...also nothing is fired when the app initially opens up.

I've narrowed this down to the fact that in these cases `mReactInstanceManager.getCurrentReactContext()` is null...for some reason.

Here's my code from `MainActivity.java`:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (mReactInstanceManager != null) {
        mReactInstanceManager.onPause();

        //send the appState back to JS
        Log.d("REACT_STATE", "Paused");  //this always fires
        if(mReactInstanceManager.getCurrentReactContext()!=null) {
            WritableMap params = Arguments.createMap();
            params.putString("currentAppState", "background");
            sendEvent(mReactInstanceManager.getCurrentReactContext(), "appStateChange", params);
        }
    }
}
```

and,

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (mReactInstanceManager != null) {
        mReactInstanceManager.onResume(this, this);

        //send the appState back to JS
        Log.d("REACT_STATE", "Resumed"); //this also always fires
        if(mReactInstanceManager.getCurrentReactContext()!=null) {
            WritableMap params = Arguments.createMap();
            params.putString("currentAppState", "foreground");
            sendEvent(mReactInstanceManager.getCurrentReactContext(), "appStateChange", params);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the emitter code:

```
private void sendEvent(ReactContext reactContext,
                       String eventName,
                       @Nullable WritableMap params) {
    reactContext
            .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
            .emit(eventName, params);
}
```

The JS side of things is set up OK and working - I can provide this code if it helps. I'm fairly certain my issue lies on this side. Am I trying to emit this at the wrong time? Do I need to move it elsewhere? Any advice is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've managed to sort this. I created a new Plugin Package `AppStateAndroid` which emits back to the JS. This is added at the right time in the app lifecycle and works perfectly. I'm going to post the code up to GitHub (http://github.com/scgough) but for anyone that's wondering here you go:

```
public class AppStateAndroidPlugin extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

private static final String PLUGIN_NAME = "AppStateAndroid";

private ReactContext mReactContext;

protected Activity activity = null;

protected Activity getActivity(){
    return this.activity;
}

public AppStateAndroidPlugin(ReactApplicationContext reactContext, Activity activity) {
    super(reactContext);

    this.mReactContext = reactContext;

    this.activity = activity;
    this.activity.getApplication().registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
}

private void sendEvent(ReactContext reactContext,
                       String eventName,
                       @Nullable WritableMap params) {

    Log.d(PLUGIN_NAME, "Sending Event"+params.toString());
    reactContext
            .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
            .emit(eventName, params);
}
...
@Override
public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
    Log.d(PLUGIN_NAME, "Resumed");
    if(mReactContext!=null) {
        WritableMap params = Arguments.createMap();
        params.putString("currentAppState", "active");
        sendEvent(mReactContext, "appStateChange", params);
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
    Log.d(PLUGIN_NAME, "Paused");
    if(mReactContext!=null) {
        WritableMap params = Arguments.createMap();
        params.putString("currentAppState", "background");
        sendEvent(mReactContext, "appStateChange", params);
    }
}
...
@Override
public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {
    Activity myActivity = this.getActivity();
    if (activity == myActivity){
        myActivity.getApplication().unregisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
    }
}

@Override
public String getName() {
    return PLUGIN_NAME;
}
}
```

You'll need a package file for this then in your main activity:

```
mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
            .setApplication(getApplication())
            .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
            .setJSMainModuleName("index.android")
            .addPackage(new MainReactPackage())
            .addPackage(new AppStateAndroidPluginPackage(this))
            ...
```

Comment: @Srikanth thanks. Glad you like. Up vote etc please! :-)

Comment: I upvoted it.. I have a Question if u can help me please.. I have a menu button and onclick() of the menu button I need to send the event

Comment: @Srikanth best to post your question in it's own post with code fully explaining the issue

Answer (score 1):

[GitHub: Is there any callback for android when ReactContext is created in MainAcitivity? #3887](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3887#issuecomment-332299138)

You could avoid this by listening to the onReactContextInitialized callback.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getReactInstanceManager().addReactInstanceEventListener(this);
}  

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    getReactInstanceManager().removeReactInstanceEventListener(this);
}
```

When your ReactContext is created, the callback will be notified:

```
@Override
public void onReactContextInitialized(ReactContext context) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Here's your valid ReactContext");
}
```

OR:

```
reactInstanceManager.addReactInstanceEventListener(context -> {
    // first, grab the current context
    String eventName = "RevLoadPluginModulePathsEvent";

    // a WritableMap is the equivalent to a JS Object:
    // the React native bridge will convert it as is
    WritableMap params = Arguments.createMap();
    params.putString("MyCustomEventParam", "REV LOAD MODULES . . . .");

    revInitReactActivity.revSendReactEvent(context, eventName, params);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for ways to get the ReactContext instance from Activity, using

```
 this.getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager().getCurrentReactContext();
```

instead of

```
 this.getReactInstanceManager().getCurrentReactContext();
```

Although I don't understand why...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15281833)

Comment: @anticafe I believe this is exactly an answer to the question. The problem in the question was not being able to getting the ReactContext instance from the activity. This solves it.

Comment: @user2718861 getReactNativeHost() does not exist inside an Activity. Where would you call this?